# When does Docker write to iptables?

Tags: docker, iptables

When the Docker daemon uses icc=true and iptables=true defaults, iptables are not written when linking --link containers.  Only when I set icc=false iptables=true does iptables get written when linking containers with --link.  Is this an error or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

With `--icc=true`, containers have unrestricted network access to each other so no iptables rules are necessary to support `--link`.  Only with `--icc=false` are there restrictions for which Docker needs to create exceptions.